# Перебор массива средствами php

Tags: php, массивы, json

Структура массива:

```
{"id":31,"site":"dev.2","total":"11"}
{"id":42,"sitу":"dev.1","total":"13"}
{"id":63,"site":"dev.2","total":"15"}
```

Требуется прогнать в цикле и вывести на экран:
Сайт|Cумма|
dev.2|26|
dev.1|13|

Comment: у вас json? или вы просто так изобразили PHP массив?

Comment: массив приходит из MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вот вариант:

```
<?php
$array = ['{"id":31,"site":"dev.2","total":"11"}',
          '{"id":42,"site":"dev.1","total":"13"}',
          '{"id":63,"site":"dev.2","total":"15"}'];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $elem) {
    $json = json_decode($elem);
    if(isset($newArray[$json->site])) {
        // Если ключ есть, то суммируем с текущим значением
        $newArray[$json->site] += intval($json->total);
    } else {
        // Если ключа нет, то добавляем его
        $newArray[$json->site] = intval($json->total);
    }
}

var_dump($newArray); // Тут массив вида ['dev.2' => 26, 'dev.1' => 13]
```

Comment: Вопрос, когда я хочу идентифицировать элемент, то выскакивает ошибка
Как сделать чтобы я мог нагружать больше элементов чтобы в итоге иметь массив в массиве.
Вообщем $newArray[$json->site]['total'] = intval($json->total); не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Исходный массив
$array = [
    ["id" => 31,"site" => "dev.2", "total" => "11"],
    ["id" => 42,"site" => "dev.1", "total" => "13"],
    ["id" => 63,"site" => "dev.2", "total" => "15"]
];

// Выводим заголовок таблицы
echo 'Сайт|Сумма<br>';

// Проходимся по каждому подмассиву исходного массива
foreach($array as $elem)
{
    // Выводим нужные данные каждого элемента
    echo $elem['site'].' '.$elem['total'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если данные приходят из MySQL, то MySQL'ом и сложили бы.

Запрос примерно такой:

```
SELECT `site` , COUNT( `site` ) AS `count_site`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `site`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: SELECT `site` , sum( `total` ) AS `sum` FROM `table` GROUP BY `site`